# How to use same wide char string format for windows and linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows

Currently, I have some code that will running on Windows/Linux. Now I have a problem when output some information.
On windows, I use _vsnwprintf_s() to support variable parameter. So it support below format.

```
Log0(L"111");
Log1(L"%s", L"22");
Log2(L"%s, %d", L"33", 44);
```

On Linux, I can not use vswprintf to format string, but it need use `%ls` to format wide string.

```
Debug0(L"111");
Debug1(L"%ls", L"22");
```

Currently, I want to wrapper a unified function InfoX() to support cross-platform, so it internally will use LogX() or DebugX() base on current OS type.
As you can see, on windows, I will use **%s** to format wide string, but will use **%ls** on linux. I do not known how to input at **???** in Info2() function.

```
Info2(L"???", L"22");
```

Comment: Are you compiling your code using the C++ compiler or the C compiler? I think you should specify either the c++ tag or the c tag, not both.

Comment: I am using g++, I will update tag.

Comment: Don't you mean `swprintf`? You're not passing a `va_list`.

Comment: According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx), the `%ls` specifier requires a wide-char string: "An `ls`, `lS`, `ws` or `wS` type specifier is synonymous with `S` in **printf** functions and with `s` in **wprintf** functions." So you could use `%ls` for both Linux and Windows. (The format `%S` seems to be non-standard and is different on both platforms.)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use stl library ? It is the better tool to answer to your problem.
You use wide char so std::wstring is the best solution.
To create your "wstring" value you use "wstringstream" and you don't need to format your charaters.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void LOG(std::wstring _sLog)
{
    std::wcout << _sLog << '\n';
    //Your LOG code
}

int main()
{

    std::wstringstream oss;
    std::wstring wideValue(L"my wide value :");
    oss << wideValue << 101;
    std::wstring s = oss.str();
    LOG(s);

    return 0;
}
```